# Object 0 has no method 'preventDefault'

Tags: javascript, jquery

im stuck in this situation where it loops and when i prevent it to Loop when it is triggered

Here is my Code

```
 $("#shiftForm").on('submit',
    function gvDDLValidation() {
        var gvDetDDLs = $('#positionShiftGrid').find("input[name=shiftDay]");
        $.each(gvDetDDLs, function () {
            var duplicateExists = false;
            var ddlShift = $("#ddlShiftDay option:selected").text();
            var currVal = $(this).val();
            gvDetDDLs.not(this).each(function (e) {  <--- where i trigger error
                e.preventDefault(); <--- where i trigger error
                if (ddlShift == currVal) {
                    duplicateExists = true;
                    alert("Duplicate entry is not allowed");
                    $(this).focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
        return true;
    });
```

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think `e` is an event object there.

Comment: It's not... it's an `index`. Get `e` from `gvDDLValidation`. It should remain valid throughout the inherited scope.

Comment: @NickC What should i do

Comment: @DevlshOne can you help me with this situation?

Comment: `function gvDDLValidation(e) {`  <-- passing the event object to callback function. Otherwise there's no `e` in the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

A little re-write:

```
$("#shiftForm").on('submit', function(e) // "e" here represents the "submit" event, is that what you want?
    {
        var gvDetDDLs = $('#positionShiftGrid').find("input[name=shiftDay]");
        $.each(gvDetDDLs, function ()
            {
                var duplicateExists = false;
                // are you sure you don't want ".val()" on the next line?
                var ddlShift = $("#ddlShiftDay option:selected").text();
                // "$(this)" refers to the current "gvDetDDLs" from the "$.each" statement, is this what you want?
                var currVal = $(this).val();
                // what is "this" supposed to represent on the next line?
                gvDetDDLs.not(this).each(function ()
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // maybe "e.stopPropagation();" would be better?
                        if (ddlShift == currVal) {
                            duplicateExists = true;
                            alert("Duplicate entry is not allowed");
                            $(this).focus(); // focus where, exactly?
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
        return true;
    }
);
```

Comment: This does not prevent "alert("Duplicate Entry is not Allowed") From showing. . it just loop on how many duplicate value and show everytime it detects duplicate value

Comment: Sorry, try this instead. I didn't realize that your preventDefault placement was crucial.

Comment: sir its not working , and when the alert pops up , other submits are not working , Thanks

Comment: When triggering infinite loop 
error shown 
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Maybe you should use a jsFiddle and post your HTML markup, as well. See my latest edit....

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct `e` parameter to prevent the form submit. This should be done on the submit handler. Also the syntax of your submit handler is incorrect. It should be an anonymous function and you do not need to return true or false from it:

```
$("#shiftForm").on('submit', function(e) {
    var gvDetDDLs = $('#positionShiftGrid').find("input[name=shiftDay]");
    $.each(gvDetDDLs, function () {
        var duplicateExists = false;
        var ddlShift = $("#ddlShiftDay option:selected").text();
        var currVal = $(this).val();
        gvDetDDLs.not(this).each(function () {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (ddlShift == currVal) {
                duplicateExists = true;
                alert("Duplicate entry is not allowed");
                $(this).focus();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not prevent "alert("Duplicate Entry is not Allowed") From showing. . it just loop on how many duplicate value and show everytime it detects duplicate value

Comment: Yes, you are right, you could return false from the $.each to break out of the iteration.

Comment: error shown 

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 0):

You can run my demo code and see what the error means.

When you loop over an array and expect to call a method you need to validate that it exists, first.

```
var arr = [0, {test: function(){}}];

// the error - Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'test'
//arr.forEach(function(e) {
//  e.test();
//});

    // the right way
arr.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e && e.test) {
        e.test();
    } else {
        console.log("no valid element or no support for method 'test'");
    }
});
```